# How to search for and select items from a QListView?

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit, qlistview

I have a `QLineEdit` and a `QListView`. I use `QStringListModel` to populate the `QListView` with items.

If I type something in the `QLineEdit`, how can I find and select an item from the `QListView` that begins with the text that I am typing in the `QLineEdit`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general approach is:

- Connect signal `textChanged` of the line edit to a slot of your choice.
- In this slot access the model of the list view (either you have it stored or with `model` on the list view)
- The model is inherited from `QAbstractItemModel` which has a `match` function for search ([documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#match))
- Call the `match` with `Qt::MatchStartsWith` as match flag and the appropriate role (display role) and you get a list of model indices
- The result can be zero, one, or more indices.
- Get the selection model from either the list view of the model (`selectionModel`) and call `select` with each index in the list of indices resulting from the call to `match` (some may already be selected)

---

To give some more practical advice.

Example call to match:

```
model->match(model->index(0, 0), Qt::DisplayRole, QVariant::fromValue(search_text), -1, Qt::MatchStartsWith);
```

This searches from the start to the end, taking the displayed text of the list view and compares it with a search text and returns all found matches where the displayed text starts with the search text.

Example call to select:

```
model->selectionModel()->select(index, QItemSelectionModel::Select);
```

Which will select the index (with [different flags](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qitemselectionmodel.html#SelectionFlag-enum) you can unselect or toggle the selection).

Example for iterating over the `QModelIndexList` which is a shortcut for `QList<QModelIndex>`:

```
foreach(QModelIndex modelIndex, modelIndexList)
  selectionModel->select(modelIndex, QItemSelectionModel::Select);
```